# VB.NET Unit Testing - Trying to use Assert.AreEqual to evaluate if string is greater than a certain length

Tags: vb.net

Hey everyone, I'm wondering how to evaluate an expression using the assert object. The idea is to check if a string is longer then what is minimally acceptable. For example, `Assert.AreEqual(stringName.length, >5)`. I know this method doesn't work but the concept is what I'm trying to get across. Is there a way to test this? Thanks in advance for any input anyone can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What testing framework are you using?

NUnit has `Assert.Greater(stringName.length, 5)`

For MS Test you could use `Assert.IsTrue(stringName.length >5)`

Comment: Oops, sorry for not mentioning the framework. I'm running the test on MS Test and your Assert is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.